# Encrypt and Decrypt information in a cookie

Tags: python, django

I need to securely crypt and decrypt information about users ( name, surname and user_id ) in cookies.

What is the best way to do this ? What encryption and decryption function do I need ?

Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad idea: an attacker can do chosen-text dictionary attacks if they can guess what you might be putting in the cookie, which is quite likely, and securing a universal key is harder than looking after a database containing confidential information, because there is not much in the way of an audit trail for these kind of client-side web-based attacks.

If the cost of a security breach is low, then maybe you want to do this anyway.  Just use a [symmetric-key encryption algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm).

Comment: I need to save only name, surname and user_id ( no password and no email ). So in this case what python function is best for me ?
Thanks ^_^

Comment: @xRobot: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172486/what-pure-python-library-to-use-for-aes-256-encryption

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://www.example-code.com/python/encryption.asp
I would suggest DES or Blowfish

Comment: Probably not important for this application, but DES is considered insecure.  I recommedn AES.